# Excel/R (?) Pie Chart with Subsections

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, r

I have a two long columns of data in an excel spreadsheet. One column has an age value, the other has a number that presents the favourite colour of the person (1-12). e.g.

```
ID  AGE  FavCol
1   35     1
2   62     1
3   25     2
4   18     6
5   21     8
6   32     2
7   41     3
8   51     12
```

I want to make an "exploded" pie chat that represents both of these variables. I want the wedges to be determined by the age range the individual falls in (18-24, 25-34, 35-49, 50+), and I want each wedge to be split into 12 sections, each coloured differently to represent the colours. I've made a diagram not based on data that reflects 3 age ranges, and the favourite colours (Green, Blue, Yellow) of each individual:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MWZc.png)

How can I achieve this? The data currently sits in both an Excel Spreadsheet and an R data.frame, so an answer using either program is fine. I'm quite comfortable using Illustrator to explode and edit the colours and add labels after the chart is made. If it's not possible in these programs, where is it possible?

Comment: Please check if this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792552/create-a-pie-chart-of-ages-showing-under-30s-30-50s-and-over-50s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enclosed sample code for R (RStudio) shows some approaches (see inline comments). You can either use an external program to explode and edit the colours and add labels after the chart is made. Or use R to edit the code according to your requirements.

Please note there is a proposal for a different presentation of the data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# ----------------------------------------------------------
# populate data frame
# ----------------------------------------------------------
df <- data.frame(age = c(56,73,64,80,44,80,30,74,30,19,81,43,84,36,31,37,26,63,22,74,49,30,63,41,28),
                  favcol = c(3,8,7,2,4,8,11,4,5,4,8,8,6,5,7,11,4,6,8,3,1,2,3,5,2))

# When dealing with age data group the ages into age groups.
# Name your age groups e.g. ("18-24", "25-34", "35-49", "50+").
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sGroup <- c("18-24", "25-34", "35-49", "50+")
sGroup

# Create a new column ageGroup and use the cut function to break age into groups 
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
df$ageClass <- cut(df$age, breaks = c(18,25,35,50, Inf), labels = sGroup, right = TRUE)

# sort by ageClass
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
df <- df[order(df$ageClass, df$favcol), ]
head(df)

# quickly count the unique values of one or more variables into a tibble
# optional: mutate prop
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mydata <- df %>% count(ageClass, favcol) %>%
          mutate(prop = n/sum(n)*100)
mydata

# Basic piechart
ggplot(mydata, aes(x="", y=n, fill=ageClass)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0)

# Basic piechart
ggplot(mydata, aes(x="", y=n, fill=ageClass)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  
  theme_void() # remove background, grid, numeric labels

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Proposal for a different presentation of the data
# see also: https://cardiomoon.github.io/webr/reference/PieDonut.html
# -------------------------------------------------------
library(moonBook)
library(webr)

PieDonut(mydata,
         aes(pies= ageClass, donuts = favcol, count = n),
         explode=2,
         ratioByGroup=T,
         addDonutLabel = F,
         labelpositionThreshold = 0.4,
         donutLabelSize = 3,
         use.labels = F,
         title="Title",
         maxx = 1.5,
         r0=0,
         showPieName=FALSE)
```

**Outcome (examples):**

1. Pie chart example.

[image]

2. Pie donut chart example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did this once with three different pies. I didn't bother exploding them, I simply made some data transparent, as well as the chart backgrounds, then misaligned the charts so the remaining visible parts looked like your exploded sample.

Not sure it's really the best way to show the data, but it's too late to think of anything else.